# Loop in python calls a c++ program and shall return to loop after time

Tags: python, for-loop, time-limiting

I got two for-loops, the inner one calls a c++ program (here replaced by editor emacs), that program have to be terminated after a certain time. Additionally for one concentration each 'acceleration' (1, 2, 3, 4) shall be calculated parallel for speeding up and then again for the next concentration each acceleration shall be calculated.

My problem is that with using timelimit for terminating the c++ program the python programm does not return to the loop for calculating the next concentration, it just stops.

I wrote already a more easier program and tried also subprocess to open the c++ program but it didn't terminate after a certain time. I used timelimit as well. Thanks for help!

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import subprocess as sub

x = set([1, 2, 3, 4, ])
y = set([11, 21, ])

def j_in_y(i):
     for j in y: #concentration
         print i+j
         cll = 'timelimit -t5 -T2 emacs' #c++ program call, for test emacs
         os.system(cll)

for i in x: #acceleration
     pool = Pool(processes=3)
     pool.apply_async(j_in_y, (i,))
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add

```
pool.join()
```

At the end of your main loop, to avoid your python process to terminate before the inner loops are done.  The main thread won't wait for the threads in the pool otherwise.

Comment: Sry I just forgot to write in here. But anyhow it does not terminate.